# How can I stop reading input when a specific character is entered?

Tags: scheme

I am trying to implement my own subtract function in Scheme.  I have to use the apply method to apply subtraction to the user's input.  The thing is, the user input must be between (), [], or {}  (I'm writing a small interpreter for a small language).  I have the code already managing the opening bracket fine, but my issue is using the apply method for the rest.  I need to read only the data entered before the closing bracket.  Is there a way to read the input and stop at the delimiter ")", "]", or "{}".  Even if you can steer me in the right direction for just a single delimiter, I could make the rest work.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
(define subt (lambda (x)
             (apply - (read-line))))
```

But I want it to stop reading at the closing bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` procedure reads Scheme forms between `#\(` and `#\)`.  Assuming parens are a suitable delimiter the following works:

```
(define subt
  (lambda (x)
    (apply - (read))))
```

Of course, `-` expects numbers and `read` will return any Scheme form.

```
> (subt 'ignore)
(10 5 3 1)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you find an opening bracket, add it to a stack and start adding the characters you read along the way to a data structure, say, a new list or syntax tree (notice: you have to read character by character, no line by line as is implied in your code!). Whenever you find the closing bracket corresponding to the topmost element in the stack, pop the topmost bracket from the stack and stop adding elements to the list of characters - at this point you know that a complete expression has been read in the data structure in use and can go ahead with its evaluation.

Also, you should separate the code for parsing the input from the code for evaluating it, in such a way that the evaluator receives the list, syntax tree or whatever intermediate representation is returned by the parser and doesn't have to worry about reading characters, finding matching brackets, etc.

**EDIT**

If you're not required to implement a parser from scratch, a simple solution involving built-in procedures will do, as suggested by @GoZoner : use the `read` procedure making sure of entering the input numbers between `()` and ending the input with a return, like this:

```
(define (subt)
  (apply - (read)))

(subt)
 input: (10 2 1)
output: 7
```